# Cannot import name 'iscode' from 'xdis' when using 'trepan3k'

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering, trepan

I am trying to use trepan3k to debug a `.pyc` file. However, when I typed the command `trepan3k flag.pyc`, it gave me the error: `Cannot import name 'iscode' from 'xdis'`.

I am using MacOS, with Python 3.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just released version [1.0.0 of trepan3k](https://pypi.org/project/trepan3k/) and that should address this problem. This is fault (dependency hell) and I'm sorry for the trouble here.

More generally there was a certain looseness in specifying dependencies in trepan3k that allowed an older `xdis` to be used when it shouldn't have.

There has been some major upheaval in all of that code in order to support a bytecode interpreter written in Python. See https://pypi.org/project/x-python/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the xdis (https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis) installed correctly?  however we need more information.